# How to download the python packages on windows?

Tags: python, windows, pip, command-prompt

First of all, i'd like to mention that I'm a student, we take a python course in college and develop/test on Linux. I'm trying to replicate the experiments but having issues setting it up.I'm used to just using `pip` to install packages I need, however when I try these commands in the prompt  python `-m pip install -U pip setuptools` and others in the documentation I just get that python is not recognized nor is pip.(although pip, by default, is part of my installed packages). My issues continue to when I try to paste content in my prompt or copy from it. Basically a complete beginner's issues, I did refer to some of your answers but they were mostly too advanced for my liking.

Comment: What is the error you are getting ?

Comment: 'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 0):

Run `python get-pip.py`.
Since you said it is installed, this will update it. If it didn't work then I'm sorry, that's my knowledge limitation on Python :/

Comment: I'm sorry then :/